# SQL to split a column values into rows in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I have data in the below way in a column.  The data within the column is separated by two spaces.

`4EG  C6CC  C6DE  6MM  C6LL  L3BC  C3`

I need to split it into as beloW.  I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR to do it but looks like it's not in the SQL toolkit. Any suggestions?

```
1. 4EG 
2. C6CC
3. C6DE
4. 6MM 
5. C6LL
6. L3BC
7. C3
```

Answer (score 1):

This has ben answered here: http://nz2nz.blogspot.com/2016/09/netezza-transpose-delimited-string-into.html?m=1

Please note the comment at the button about the best performing way of use if array functions. I have measured the use of regexp_extract_all_sp() versus repeated regex matches and the benefit can be quite large

Answer (score 0):

The examples from `nz2nz.blogpost.com` are hard to follow. I was able to piece together this method:

```sql
with
   n_rows as (--update on your end
      select row_number() over(partition by 1 order by some_field) as seq_num
      from any_table_with_more_rows_than_delimited_values
   )
   
   , find_values as ( -- fake data
     select 'A' as id, '10,20,30' as orig_values
     union select 'B', '5,4,3,2,1'
   )
   
select
    id,
    seq_num,
    orig_values,
    array_split(orig_values, ',') as array_list,
    get_value_varchar(array_list, seq_num) as value
from
    find_values
    cross join n_rows
where
    seq_num <= regexp_match_count(orig_values, ',') + 1 -- one row for each value in list
order by
    id,
    seq_num
```

[image]